# Parallelograms circumscribing an ellipse

Tags: geometry

[image]

In lemma 1 of Newton's tract on motion that he sent to Edmund Halley in 1684, it states that "all parallelograms described around a given ellipse are equal"

Can anyone prove for the case given in this diagram.

PS: my source for the above quote and this diagram is the book "the key to Newton's dynamics" by J. Bruce Brackenridge.

Comment: Equal in what respect? Area?

Comment: "Equal" in this case means "with the same area".

Comment: Yes equal as in equal areas.

Comment: Which "Lemma 1", exactly?

Comment: I'm sorry I made a mistake there. That's lemma 1 of his tract on motion that he sent to Edmund Halley in 1684. That appears as lemma 12 in the Principia.

Comment: This lemma was used to solve the Kepler problem of planetary orbit. That is why I am looking for a proof of its validity

Comment: Aaron, first do it for a circle. All parallelograms around a circle will be rhombuses, so not that bad. Once you have that, the ellipse situation is just a linear transformation of a circle figure. I guess you want the unit circle and the x,y axes to be the diagonals of the rhombus, so a little trigonometry, not much

Comment: There are other mistakes. All parallelograms around an ellipse do not have the same area.

Comment: @WillJagy In fact the statement made by Newton is different, see my answer.

Answer (score 7):

The exact statement, given by Newton as Lemma XII, is the following:

> All parallelograms circumscribed about any conjugate diameters of a
> given ellipse or hyperbola are equal among themselves.

A proof can be found, for instance, on [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Theorem_of_Apollonios_on_conjugate_diameters), where it is stated as "Theorem of Apollonios on conjugate diameters".

A more geometrical proof can be given by considering an ellipse as a circle stretched along a given direction.

Any circle has infinite squares circumscribed to it, all equal among them, their tangency points being the endpoints of two perpendicular diameters. After the stretching, the circle becomes an ellipse, the two perpendicular diameters become a couple of conjugate diameters of the ellipse, and the circumscribed square becomes a circumscribed parallelogram.

The areas of the stretched figures are all in the same ratio with the areas of the figures before stretching, and as all circumscribed squares are equal, then all circumscribed parallelogram have the same area.

Comment: good; square around a circle, not just any rhombus.

Answer (score 2):

Summary: the item requested is WRONG

We choose a radius of the unit circle in the first quadrant, call it $(a,b)$ with both positive and $a^2 + b^2 = 1.$ That is where we want this edge of the rhombus to be tangent to the circle, so this tangent is $$ ax+by=1 $$
With the axes, we make a right triangle. The two legs of the right triangle are lengths $\frac{1}{a}$ and $\frac{1}{b} .$ Hmmmm. The area of the triangle is $\frac{1}{2ab}$ and the area of the whole rhombus is $$  \frac{2}{ab} $$

I'm afraid this depends on the particular choice of $a,b.$ For example, choose $a = \cos \theta$ and $b = \sin \theta.$ the rhombus area is $$\frac{4}{\sin 2 \theta}$$

Which means that you are missing some hypotheses

Comment: The hypothese which is indeed missing, as given by @aretino, is that the sides of the parallelogram have to be parallel to **conjugate** diameters...

Comment: @JeanMarie thank you. I was out for a bicycle ride, I came back planning to add some lines about not expecting Newton or Kepler to be guilty of errors, also not really expecting errors from the translator(s).